# Ubuntu 64 or 32 bit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bit, difference

How i understand in Windows differences between 32 and 64 bits is that 64 can see more than 3GB Operation Memory, and how i read on many forums there says that 64bit work faster, but all recommend 32bit, why ? If 64bit can see more memory, work faster, then why still there is 32bit, and why some people recomemnd 32bit for Ubuntu instead of 64 ?

Comment: I *don't* recommend Ubuntu 32bit!  But there are still many 32bit CPUs out there, Ubuntu 64bit will not run on them.  Maybe they thought it was better to be conservative when they recommend something to a newcomer.

Comment: Okay, thanks ! 
So i can not to run 32bit programs on Ubuntu 64, like on Windows i can run 32bit programs, if i have 64bit, but not vice versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stability, better software and drivers in general, also many 64 bit programs are just a "raw" porting from their 32 bit counterpart.

Unlike what many people think, a 32 bit kernel has no problem in managing more than ~4 Gb of RAM, infact enterprise-grade 32 bit solutions can use PAE kernels that work just fine.

Regarding Windows 32 bit desktop the answer is simple: it's licensed that way, so the user can't use more than ~3.5Gb of RAM because the OS was built and shipped with that limitation.

Comment: Thanks!
So for desktop laptop which version you would recommend ?

Comment: @kxc try a 64 bit version first, if you have no problem with the drivers, than just stick with it. If you need to run 32 bit programs you should google for `ubuntu multilib` .

Comment: I found your answer misleading.  The 32bit OS can manage up to 64 GB of RAM thanks to PAE, but each 32bit process **does** have the 4 GB limit.  You should have clarified this point.

Comment: @nodakai a process it's not an OS, and since we are talking about OSs I don't feel the need to clarify that ... anyway that kind of limitation is often times enforced by the OS vendor too, so 4Gb can be the "physical" limit, but nothing prevents an OS vendor to limit the size even more, it's something that is really OS-specific.